# In Drupal 8 i want list my values in new page

Tags: 8

I want to display the values of my data from table(**exam_register**) in the mentioned path.

Listed path how can i bring up values table format. And permission only to admin, i want to setup.

```
 exam_register_list:
 path: 'exam_register/list'
 defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\exam_register\Form\ListForm'
    _title: 'Exam Page'
 requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

Kindly suggest me sample example of db_select statement.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! This question is too broad for us: You can find many examples on how to use `db_select()` on api.drupal.org. If there is anything specific you don't understand, you could ask a question about that. Requiring an example of how to use a function/method is not asking a question.

Comment: Notice also that showing the definition of a route doesn't make the question less generic. You are showing something that is not even related to using the function for which you want an example.

Comment: Future readers... note that this is made much easier with entities and Views. While it is possible to construct your own controller and output, using Views is typically the easier route (accounts for paging, filtering, caching, AJAX, etc of data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the sample code to fetch data from table `node_field_data` and list the data in table format.

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\mymodule\Controller\HelloController.
 */
namespace Drupal\mymodule\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

class HelloController extends ControllerBase {
  public function content() {

    $query = \Drupal::database()->select('node_field_data', 'nfd');
    $query->fields('nfd', ['nid','title','type']);
    $result = $query->execute();

    foreach($result as $row) {
      $rows[] = array('data' => (array) $row);
    }

    $build = array(
      '#markup' => t('List of Data')
    );
    $header = array('Nid', 'Title','Type');
    $build['location_table'] = array(
      '#theme' => 'table',
      '#header' => $header,
      '#rows' => $rows
    );
    $build['pager'] = array(
      '#type' => 'pager'
    );
    return $build;
  }
}
```

The output will be shown as below.
[image]

**Updates**

Modify your form to include the result form the controller. Refer the following code.

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
# Include controller.
use Drupal\mymodule\Controller\HelloController;

class SampleDataForm extends FormBase {
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'sample_form';
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

$statistics = new HelloController;
$value = $statistics->content();
    $form['table_data'] = array(
      '#markup' => \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot($value['location_table']),
    );
    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  }
}
```

Comment: I got the output. By using this but in controller(page) only we can display the values of tables(controllername.php). Can't be displayed in Form(formname.php) without submit function.

Comment: On using the (tableselect) option output is not showing. It tells no record found.

Comment: With Drupal 8, you don't need to use `drupal_render()`. Also, `#markup` filters the markup.

Comment: @B.lakshman That is because there aren't records found basing on the search criteria.

Comment: In table-select i want add the Edit/Delete field. So i changed like this foreach($result as $row) {$rows[] = array('data' => (array) $row);} I changed it to ($url = Url::fromRoute("profile_register_edition", $option);
$internal = \Drupal::l(t('Edit'), $url);) ($rows[] = array($row->id, $row->name,$internal). Any way shortest define in two <td> in one row. If not we manually code table tag like in drupal 7.